# Error when importing numba in Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, installation, cython

I have just installed numba in my Ubuntu 13.04 via pip-3.3, as an alternative to numpy and cython to make calculations, but every time i try to import it in Python i get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error and Python exists:

```
esteban@esteban-Inspiron-1525:~$ python3
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:30:32) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numba
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
esteban@esteban-Inspiron-1525:~$
```

Does anyone now what could be happening?. Could it be a problem in the installation or is it that numba is not supported in python3 yet? I had this packages installed before numba:

```
llvm
cython
llvmpy
sphinx (for doc)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've recently heard that Ubuntu 13.04 has major issues with Python.

Answer (score 4):

Numba has preliminary support for Python 3.  It should work, but I don't think it's received as much testing.  Which version of numba did you try?

Also, how did you install llvm and llvmpy and which version of numpy do you have installed?

Comment: Thanks you Travis. I'm installing both llvm and llvmpy via "Sudo apt-get install" The numba version I tried was **numba-0.8.1.tar.gz** using "sudo pip-3.3 install numba". Also, I'm getting this error in the installation `UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.3/numba/_version.py
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/numba/pyextensibletype/extensibletype/test/test_perfecthashing.py", line 71
        print i, "table building took", t, "seconds."
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax` I don't know what can be happening. ..